# Error while loading shared libraries during Java 1.6 Configuration in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jvm

I installed Java and when I executed jps

its throwing

> jps: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The Commands I executed to configure is

```
 sudo  mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm  
 sudo cp -R jdk1.6.0_45  /usr/lib/jvm/  
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javac 1  
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java 1  
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws   /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/javaws 1  
 sudo update-alternatives --config javac  
 sudo update-alternatives --config java  
 sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
```

Comment: That is not where the problem lies. What is jps? If it is not a programming tool this question probably belongs on superuser.com, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is due to missing command

> **sudo ./jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin**

Then copy command should be there.